# RegExp: how to split this

Tags: regex

Its late and I'm struggling, could some one please help me out.
I want to split this...

```
[stuffa1,stuffa2],[stuffb1,stuffb2]
```

into

```
[stuffa1,stuffa2]
[stuffb1,stuffb2]
```

via reg exp.

it could also be...

```
[stuffa1,stuffa2]
```

or

```
[stuffa1,stuffa2],[stuffb1,stuffb2],[stuffc1,stuffc2]
```

Comment: yeah - always include what language or tool you are using to execute the regex (and tag it with that language as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do this.

### Without needing regular expressions

1. Remove first character (`[`)
2. Remove last character (`]`)
3. Split on `],[`
4. Now you have pieces that look like `stuffa1,stuffa2`. If you need to, add `[` and `]` back to each string.

### Using regex that supports look-behind (and look-ahead)

Split on:

```
(?<=\]),(?=\[)
```

This will give you complete pieces that look like `[stuffa1,stuffa2]`

Comment: +1 for what will MOST LIKELY WORK... _very_ unlikely considering the syntax, but if there is some sort of escaping that allows `\]` inside a value (not too incredibly likely) and THEN someone happens to put a `,[` just after one of those (i.e.: `blah\],[blah`, then BOTH of these solutions would break... but is that likely to happen? idunno...

Answer (score 2):

You can use positive lookahead and lookbehind to add the square braces (`[]`) to the delimiter without including them in what is stripped out as the delimiter itself:

```
String input = "[stuffa1,stuffa2],[stuffb1,stuffb2]";
String[] groups = input.split("(?<=\\]),(?=\\[)");
```

Language: Java.  The "pure" regex is `(?<=\]),(?=\[)`